# Checking if an object already exists in collection

Tags: c#, list, equality

I am learning programming and my problem is that I have a bunch of objects and I want to add these objects to a list only if the list does not already contain that object. Secondly if the object is already contained I want to ignore that object and add the next one instead. I think I have got the first part working just need some help with part two. Many thanks.

```
PartyGroup partyGroup = new PartyGroup(); 

using (AseDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader()) 
{ 
    while (reader.Read()) 
    {  
        if (!myPartyGroupList.Contains(partyGroup)) 
        { 
            partyGroup.PartyGroupID = Convert.ToInt32(reader["party_group_id"]); 
            partyGroup.PartyGroupName = reader["party_group_name"].ToString(); 
            partyGroup.PersonList = myPersonList; 

            myPartyGroupList.Add(partyGroup); 
        } 
        else 
        { 
            //?? 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When comparing it is better to use comparison with respect to a identifier, which in your case is the PartyGroupId. If you use contains then the default overload of Contains() then the hash value of the object in the list is used for comparison.

So rather than leave the comparison to .NET you can create a custom IEqualityComparer implementation or use Linq's Where clause as follows.

```
using (AseDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader()) 
{ 
    while (reader.Read()) 
    {  
        int groupId = Convert.ToInt32(reader["party_group_id"]);

        if (partyGroupsList.Where(partyGroup => partyGroup.PartyGroupID == groupId).Any() == false)
        {
           PartyGroup newPartyGroup = new PartyGroup()
                                      {
                                          PartyGroupID = groupId,
                                          PartyGroupName = reader["party_group_name"].ToString(),
                                          PersonList = myPersonList
                                      };

           partyGroupsList.Add(newPartyGroup);                 
        } 

        // If object already exists in the list then do not add, continue 
        // to the next row.   
    } 
}
```

Another suggestion is to rename to PartyGroup class members as:

```
class PartyGroup
 {
   public int ID { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public IList PersonList { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Devendra this option worked for me. I wonder if you could explain the following line to aid my understanding: if (myPartyGroupList.Where(partyGroup => partyGroup.PartyGroupID == groupId).Any() == false)

Comment: if (myPartyGroupList.Where(partyGroup => partyGroup.PartyGroupID == groupId).Any() == false) can be interpreted as: Part1: SELECT partyGroup FROM partyGroupList WHERE partyGroup.PartyGroupID = groupID; Part2: Are there are Any results in the previous query? - The final result is a boolean value (true/false). The result is true if there are a result rows found, otherwise the result is false. For more information refer MSDN resources on LINQ extensions.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. So at the moment I am getting the same  PersonList for each PartyGroup. Is there a way to say only give me the PersonList where the partyGroupId matches the current groupId in my PartyGroup object. Make sense?

Comment: The PartyGroup object (newPartyGroup) is created only when a match for the groupID is found. This newly created object's PersonList property is assigned a value from myPersonList.

Comment: Thanks this is what I thought. Thats why i'm a bit mythed that I keep getting the same group of persons (PersonList) for each PartyGroup.

Comment: Sorry just to clarify - the problem is that myPersonList contains the whole results set - including all the groupIds for each person. So at the moment each time it creates a new PartyGroup it adds all the values in myPersonList. So my question was is there a way to tell it to only add those values in myPersonList where the groupId matches the current groupID we are dealing with. (Maybe i'm missing a groupId property in Person class). Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You've got the first part down perfect.

Just remove the 'else' clause and your routine will automatically add the next element in the next iteration.  Like this:

```
while (reader.Read()) 
{ 
    if (!myPartyGroupList.Contains(partyGroup)) 
    { 
        partyGroup.PartyGroupID = Convert.ToInt32(reader["party_group_id"]); 
        partyGroup.PartyGroupName = reader["party_group_name"].ToString(); 
        partyGroup.PersonList = myPersonList; 

        myPartyGroupList.Add(partyGroup); 

    } 
}
```

Comment: +1 Beat me to it. @Ben: If you want nothing to happen then you do nothing. Not adding an item to a list is not doing anything. And by not doing anything you automatically move to the next item in your while loop.

Comment: Shouldn't the partyGroup get the new values assigned before checking if it exists in the list?  Won't this code Add the first one, then not add another because it thinks it already exists since the values are not updated?

Comment: Ah thanks guys that makes sense. However i'm only getting the first element so I suspect there is something wrong with my SQL. Thanks

Comment: Yes Tester101 I believe this is what is happening

Comment: The first partyGroup line should say:

partyGroup = new partyGroup();

Answer (score 4):

Your code has some issues. First, you're reusing the same object for each of your iterations.

Consider

```
List<Foo> foos = new List<Foo>();
Foo foo = new Foo();
foo.Bar = "Alpha";
foos.Add(foo);
foo.Bar = "Beta";
foos.Add(foo);
```

You will note that your list will have 2 items but they will reference the same object. If you iterate over the list and check `Bar`, each will return `"Beta"`.

You want to create a *new* `Foo` for each item.

```
List<Foo> foos = new List<Foo>();
Foo foo = new Foo();
foo.Bar = "Alpha";
foos.Add(foo);
Foo anotherFoo = new Foo();
anotherFoo.Bar = "Beta";
foos.Add(anotherFoo);
```

In looping terms, that basically just means create the object inside the loop instead of outside.

```
while (someCondition)
{
    Foo foo = new Foo();
    // do your work, populate the object, etc.
    // then check contains 
    if (!myList.Contains(foo))
        myList.Add(foo);
}
```

Regarding checking to see if the collection already contains the object, have you properly overriden `Equals` and `GetHashCode`? When dealing the classes, the default behavior is to simply check if the object references are equal. If you're concerned about the *values* the objects are encapsulating, then you need to provide the logic for that yourself. In your class, you need to override the `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods to implement your desired method of determining equality.

```
class Foo
{
    public string Bar { get; set; }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return this.Bar.GetHashCode();
    }

    public override bool Equals(object other)
    {
        Foo otherFoo = other as Foo;
        if (otherFoo == null)
            return false;
        else
            return this.Bar == otherFoo.Bar;
    }
}
```

Now when `Contains` seeks to determine if the object is already in the list, it will do so based upon the the values contained in the object rather than the memory reference.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using a `Hashset<PartyGroup>` to populate, and then convert it to a list.  If you have a large number of items, that's going to be significantly faster than checking the list for every item.

```
Hashset<PartyGroup> pgHash = new Hashset<PartyGroup>();

using (AseDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader()) 
{ 
    while (reader.Read()) 
    {
        PartyGroup pg = new PartyGroup();  
        partyGroup.PartyGroupID = Convert.ToInt32(reader["party_group_id"]); 
        partyGroup.PartyGroupName = reader["party_group_name"].ToString(); 
        partyGroup.PersonList = myPersonList; 
        // Add won't add an item if it already exists in the collection.
        pgHash.Add(partyGroup); 
    } 
}
// Now convert the result to a list.
myPartyGroupList = pgHash.ToList();
```

If your `PartyGroup` class doesn't implement `IEquatable<PartyGroup>`, you'll have to provide an equality comparer.  The following should work:

```
public class PartyGroupComparer:IEqualityComparer<PartyGroup>
{
    public bool Equals(PartyGroup g1, PartyGroup g2)
    {
        return g1.PartyGroupId.Equals(g2.PartyGroupId);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(PartyGroup g)
    {
        return g.PartyGroupId;
    }
}
```

And then your initialization becomes:

```
IEqualityComparer<PartyGroup> pgComparer = new PartyGroupComparer();
HashSet<PartyGroup> pgHash = new HashSet<PartyGroup>(pgComparer);
```

An alternative to the `HashSet`, as somebody else pointed out, is the `Dictionary`. That will prevent you from having to do the equality comparer.  You'll still have to convert to a list when you're done.  But that's pretty easy:

```
Dictionary<int, PartyGroup> dict = new Dictionary<int, PartyGroup>();
// populate dictionary as suggested in other answer

// now convert values to a list.
myPartyGroupList = dict.Values.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
while (reader.Read()) 
{ 
    partyGroup.PartyGroupID = Convert.ToInt32(reader["party_group_id"]); 
    partyGroup.PartyGroupName = reader["party_group_name"].ToString(); 
    partyGroup.PersonList = myPersonList; 

    if (!myPartyGroupList.Contains(partyGroup)) 
    { 
        myPartyGroupList.Add(partyGroup); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks- however this time it showed the next element but not the first :|

Answer (score 0):

First, you are checking if the object instance is in the collection, but you are only creating one instance once (outside the while loop). Therefore, when you check if  `!myPartyGroupList.Contains(partyGroup)`, it will return false the first time, so you will add the obj to the collection and then it will return false every time.

I would use a Dictionary using an Id property as the Dictionary key.

like this:

```
Dictionary <int,PartyGroup> myPartyGroupList = new Dictionary <int,PartyGroup>();

using (AseDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader()) 
{ 
    while (reader.Read()) 
    {  
        int id=Convert.ToInt32(reader["party_group_id"]); 
        if (!myPartyGroupList.ContainsKey( id )) 
        { 
            PartyGroup partyGroup = new PartyGroup(); 

            partyGroup.PartyGroupID = id; 
            partyGroup.PartyGroupName = reader["party_group_name"].ToString(); 
            partyGroup.PersonList = myPersonList; 

            myPartyGroupList.Add(id, partyGroup);  // key, value? check param order here
        } 
    } 
}
```